# CTRL+D doesn't work in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

CTRL+D (duplicates) It doesn't work in visual studio 2022 , How to change Ctrl+E,V To CTRL+D ?

Comment: The clipboard does not use CTRL+D. I only know CTRL-C (copy), CTRL-X (cut) and CTRL-V (paste). CTRL+D duplicates the current line.

Comment: Tools => Options => Keyboard => show commands containing = Edit.Duplicate 
use new shortcode in = Text Editor 
Press Shortcode keys = Ctrl+D

Answer (score 25):

I just had the same problem.
The issue for me was that Visual Studio 2022 had set the mapping scheme to `Visual C# 2005` instead of `(Default)`.

In the search bar at the top of Visual Studio 2022 (`Ctrl+Q`), search for `key bindings`, or go to Options->Environment->Keyboard.
Make sure the keyboard mapping scheme is `(Default)`.

I hope it helps.

Comment: What idiots! Thank you, Matthias.

Answer (score 5):

Go to `TOOLS` -> `Options` -> `Environment` -> `Keyboard` and then on '*Show commands containing:*' search `Edit.Duplicate` and on '*Press shortcut keys:*' press `Ctrl+D` and click on '**Assign**' button.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

*Duplicate line* is implemented via `Ctrl+E,V` as explained [here](https://dailydotnettips.com/did-you-know-now-you-can-duplicate-line-of-code-without-loosing-your-clipboard-content-within-visual-studio/).

This operation does leave the clipboard untouched.

Command and respective keys are shown in the `Edit Menu`.